# Why remove the "core" directory when executing "./configure" in Apache Ignite?

Tags: c++, ignite

I am working to install apache-ignite C++

I followed up installation guide, but `./configure` didn't work.

I think this has an error

```
root@tellus-station:/root/tmp/apache-ignite-2.7.0-src/modules/platforms/cpp# ./configure
...

checking for ANSI C header files... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
no
checking for sys/types.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for sys/stat.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for stdlib.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for string.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for memory.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for strings.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for inttypes.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for stdint.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for unistd.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
checking for dlfcn.h... rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
yes
...
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
rm: cannot remove 'core': Is a directory
```

[Detail Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnnLc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These messages should be ignored. Autoconf toolchain tries to remove `core` file (memory dump of process generated on signal such as `SIGSEGV`), but instead we have a `core/` directory in Apache Ignite that causes tool confusion.